# How can I find certain queries?

Tags: javascript

I have logged a bunch of slow queries. Now I am wondering how should I find them in Drupal. Any ideas?

Comment: is it related to the database queries?

Comment: By, "logged a bunch of slow queries", I assume you mean  you turned on the [MySQL Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html)?

Answer (score 4):

If it is related to database queries you can use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module.  You can configure this module http://www.example.com/admin/config/development/devel this will show you a list of slowest queries.